# How to apply case in where cluase along with in clause

Tags: sql

Here is my query. `@ScoreCount` may contain zero or not. If it contains zero, should consider zero, as well as null and empty character. How to do that in where clause?

```
DECLARE @ScoreCount varchar(50)
SET @ScoreCount = '2,5,0'
SELECT e.name,e.id,e.degisnation 
FROM tblEmployee e INNER JOIN Department d ON d.id = e.did 
WHERE e.degisnation = @designation AND ScoreCount IN (@ScoreCount)
```

So I done like this.

```
SELECT e.name,e.id,e.degisnation 
FROM tblEmployee e INNER JOIN Department d ON d.id = e.did 
WHERE e.degisnation =@designation AND
    CASE WHEN ScoreCount is null THEN 0 
         WHEN ScoreCount ='' THEN 0 
         ELSE ScoreCount END IN (2, 5, 0)
```

Is it right approach?

Here I made database value to null and '' first and later apply in clause.Again I have one query.How execution take place.According to me

```
step 1 from --- > Result1
step2 apply join on Result1 -->Result2
step3 apply where clause first part on Result2 -->Result3
step4 apply case part on Result3 then msidn in part check -->Result4
setp 5 select Result4
```

Here first it will change all record of result3 to appropriate msidn then do checking of msidn in clause or one by one change record of result3 to appropriate msidn then do checking of msidn in clause

Comment: I think when `ScoreCount` is a numeric value it will never become `''` if you pass `''` to that field it will become `0`, and I think you are using dynamic SQL ;).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `case` in the `where` clause.  Just use traditional logic:

```
select e.name, e.id, e.degisnation
from tblEmployee e inner join
     Department d
     on d.id = e.did
where e.degisnation = @designation and
      (ScoreCount is null or ScoreCount = '' or ScoreCount in (2, 5) )
```

I removed the `0` from the list.  I assume that it was just there for the first two conditions.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff ,thanks for ur help.There is zero,it should consider 0,null and empty value.If other than zero,don't consider null and empty.If I use above query it will give me null and empty value's record when scorecount does not contain zero.It add extra row.

Comment: @JuiTest . . . I don't follow your comment.  The logic in the `where` is pretty close to the logic in the `case` in your question.  I don't see where it would return extra rows.  In particular, your logic of `Scorecount in (@Scorecount)` doesn't make sense in the beginning of your question.  It doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use just:

```
...
    AND COALESCE(ScoreCount, 0) IN (0, 2, 5)
--or
-- AND ISNULL(ScoreCount, 0) IN (0, 2, 5)
```

Will handle them.